# translating jquery code gives me troubles, this.querySelector is not a function, from $(this).find('img')

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

so i have not found similar issue, i thought equivalent of .find is querySelector, and 'this' exist in pure JS too, i think similar script work so i hope it works the same
i am translating this function

```
 $('.my-gallery').each(function() {
  $(this).find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-size', $(this).find('img').get(0).naturalWidth + 'x' + $(this).find('img').get(0).naturalHeight);
  });
});
```

and this is my current translated code

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.my-gallery');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(){
    var a = this.querySelector('a');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, function(){
        this.getAttribute('data-size', this.querySelector('img').naturalWidth + 'x' + this.querySelector('img').naturalHeight);
    });
});
```

everything goes find but it gets stuck at **this.querySelector('img').naturalWidth**, i am not sure why beacuse this.getAttribute works fine, so why i cannot query chilren of this element

Comment: Replace `this.querySelector` with `document.querySelector`

Comment: well this just doesnt work, i think i need to get attribute from this child or what about get attribute, simply changing it to document doeasnt work i get another error linkEl.getAttribute(...) is null, so maybe i wrote the code wrongly or this thing is somehow misused

Answer (score 0):

You can do more than just translate it. You can improve on it so you don't have to use `this`. It also looks like you're trying to set the attribute and not get it, based on your jQuery code.

The below should work for you.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.my-gallery a')).forEach(function(anchor) {
  anchor.setAttribute('data-size', anchor.querySelector('img').naturalWidth + 'x' + anchor.querySelector('img').naturalHeight);
});
```

Comment: yep, this seems like correct translations, its more readable than the jquery code imo.

Comment: okay after further testing testing i get t is undefined error Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined

Comment: That error is not related to the code, unless you changed the variables. The JS console will tell you which line the error is on.